# How to use groupby command after inserting new rows to a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

[image]

I have a dataframe with some records. Then I inserted some rows, using rbind command. Now I want to group the entire dataframe using the three columns, but couldn't get it right.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 = df %>%
select(key,team, h_date) %>%
group_by(key,team, h_date)
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... why can you not group by after rbind? What error message are you getting with the above code?

Comment: Mhairi, I dont get any error messages, the result is same as the 2nd dataframe in the picture. I want to get as the 3rd dataframe

Comment: Are you sure you want to group? Do you not want to just arrange the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want to do:

```
df2 = df %>%
        select(key,team, h_date) %>%
        arrange(key, team, h_date)
```

Comment: yes, thanks Mhairi :)